# Problem with packing widget in another window

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, pack

I have a problem, I need to on button clicking pack terminal from tkterminal library in new window and destroy it(like toggle), but terminal is packing in already exists "root" window, so there is a code:

```py
def open_terminal():
    global debounce
    if debounce == True:
        global cmd
        cmd = tk.Toplevel(root)
        cmd.title("Terminal")
        global terminal
        terminal = Terminal(pady=5, padx=5)
        terminal.basename = "dolphinwriter$"
        terminal.shell = True
        terminal.pack(cmd, side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        debounce = False
        print(debounce)
    else:
        cmd.destroy()
        debounce = True
```

I'm trying this:

1. Checking if already terminal packed in root window and if yes, unpack it and pack it again
2. Upacking terminal and pack it again without checking.
   I tried to do everything described above with the pack_forget() method

Comment: what is `Terminal`? Is it a class you've written?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no, it's part of tkterminal library(https://pypi.org/project/tkterminal/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the terminals master window in the line where you pack it: `terminal.pack(cmd, side="top", fill="both", expand=True)`.

In Tkinter, assigning the master window is done when you create the object.

Corrected code:

```
def open_terminal():
    global debounce
    if debounce == True:
        global cmd
        cmd = tk.Toplevel(root)
        cmd.title("Terminal")
        global terminal
        terminal = Terminal(master=cmd, pady=5, padx=5)
        terminal.basename = "dolphinwriter$"
        terminal.shell = True
        terminal.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        debounce = False
        print(debounce)
    else:
        cmd.destroy()
        debounce = True
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To place `terminal` in `Toplevel`, you need to explicitly specify `master`, by default widgets have `root` parent.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkterminal import Terminal
from functools import partial


def open_terminal():
    root.withdraw()

    cmd = tk.Toplevel(root)
    cmd.title("Terminal")
    cmd.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", partial(on_closing, cmd))
    
    terminal = Terminal(cmd, pady=5, padx=5)
    terminal.basename = "dolphinwriter$"
    terminal.shell = True
    terminal.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


def on_closing(cmd):
    cmd.destroy()
    root.deiconify()


root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="new_window", fg="Black", command=open_terminal)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```